# Bash script rsync --include-from fail

Tags: backup, bash, scripting, rsync

I have writted a bash script to backup folders and files from a machine to our backup server.
My goal is to exclude all the files older than 6 months from this weekly backup.
To do that, I used a find command to build a txt file which contains the path of these files.

```
find . -type f -mtime -200 -fprintf $SCRIPT_DIR/Exclusions.txt "%P\n"
```

And then I used the option "--include-from" of rsync.

```
rsync . -e ssh -qrtl --exclude-from=$SCRIPT_DIR/Exclusions.txt $USER@$DEST_SRV:$DEST_DIR
```

The result was the backup worked but not the inclusion. So all the files were backuped even these older than 6 months.

How can I do for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to man pages,

```
--exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN
--exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
--include=PATTERN       don't exclude files matching PATTERN
--include-from=FILE     read include patterns from FILE
```

The exclusion is made reading pattern from files, and not according to the files names themselves.

I agree including/excluding files according to names could be handful as well, but this is not how it works.

You could try something like this in order to include files newer than 1 week ago:

```
--files-from=<(find . -mtime -7 -print0)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The task never ends and doesn't backup any files on the server.

Comment: Please provide the exact command line which your say never ends

Comment: rsync . -e ssh -qrtl --files-from=<(find . -mtime -7 -print0) $USER@$DEST_SRV:$DEST_DIR

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved my issue!
The "find" line stay the same:

```
find . -type f -mtime -200 -fprintf $SCRIPT_DIR/includes.txt "%P\n"
```

And I use the "--files-from" option instead of "--exclude-from"

```
rsync . -e ssh -qrtl --files-from=$SCRIPT_DIR/includes.txt $USER@$DEST_SRV:$DEST_DIR
```